# How can I make this react Layout private

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I need to prevent the user from going to the layout component unless the user is authenticated.

```
const router = createBrowserRouter([
  {
    path: "/",
    element: <Layout />,
    children: [
      {
        path: "/",
        element: <Home />
      },
      {
        path: "/users",
        element: <Users />
      },
      {
        path: "/products",
        element: <Products />
      },
      {
        path: "/profile",
        element: <Profile />
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    path: "/login",
    element: <Login />
  },
  {
    path: "/register",
    element: <SignUp />
  },
])
```

I tried to create a component where this component going to check if there is a token if token exit return `<Outlet />` else return go to login page.

Answer (score -1):

You can just wrap your protected components with a RequireAuth Component:

```
{
   path: "/profile",
   element: <RequireAuth><Profile /></RequireAuth>
}
```

RequireAuth would look something like this:

```
import { useLocation, Navigate, Outlet } from "react-router-dom";
import { useAuth } from "../hooks/useAuth";

const RequireAuth = () => {
  const auth = useAuth();
  const location = useLocation();

  return auth.isAuthenticated ? (
    <Outlet />
  ) : (
    <Navigate to="/login" state={{ from: location }} replace />
  );
};

export default RequireAuth;
```

[React-Router Outlet](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/components/outlet)

[React-Router Navigate](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/components/navigate)